# Python: How to output the variable based on the maximum value obtained?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a list of DNA sequences as given below. I would like to get the consensus sequence which is the highest frequency obtain in that particular position.

**test.txt**

```
>human
ATCAATTGCT
>human
GCTAGCTAGC
>human
GCTAGCTAGC
>human
GCTGATCGGC
>human
GCTTACAACG
```

Using the code below, I obtain the total A, C, G, and T from each position.

**Code**

```
from Bio import motifs
output=open("test_output.txt","a")
with open("test.txt") as handle:
    motif = motifs.read(handle, 'sites')
    output.write(str(motif.counts))
```

**Example output**

```
        0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9
A:   1.00   0.00   0.00   3.00   3.00   0.00   1.00   3.00   0.00   0.00
C:   0.00   4.00   1.00   0.00   0.00   3.00   1.00   0.00   2.00   3.00
G:   4.00   0.00   0.00   1.00   2.00   0.00   0.00   2.00   3.00   1.00
T:   0.00   1.00   4.00   1.00   0.00   2.00   3.00   0.00   0.00   1.00
```

How can I get the output of each bases stated in the last column?

**Desired output**

```
    0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9
A:   1.00   0.00   0.00   3.00   3.00   0.00   1.00   3.00   0.00   0.00
C:   0.00   4.00   1.00   0.00   0.00   3.00   1.00   0.00   2.00   3.00
G:   4.00   0.00   0.00   1.00   2.00   0.00   0.00   2.00   3.00   1.00
T:   0.00   1.00   4.00   1.00   0.00   2.00   3.00   0.00   0.00   1.00
     G      C      T      A      A      C      T      A      G      C
```

Comment: Put your values into a [counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) and retrieve the most often referred ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Motifs has a consensus method that does exactly what you want:

```
 output.write("\t".join(list(motif.consensus)))
```